# Set optional keys in Laravel Push Plugin

Tags: laravel-4, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Currently I am building api using Laravel4. Recently i needed to use Push Notification for GCM. Luckly i found a plugin https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification . I can sent out notification successfully.

### Problems

1. Firstly when GCM arrived , it overwrite the previous one.
2. Secondly I have no idea how to set those keys such as "collapse_key" , "delay_while_idle" .

This is how i set keys currently

```
 $message = PushNotification::Message($msg,array(
        'msgcnt'=> 1,
        'title'=>$event->title,
        'msgtype' => $msg ,
        'collapseKey' => 'invited'
    ));
```

but **collapseKey** is not working . Any idea ! Thanks

Comment: 1. If you want to keep old GCM, why not store them in a database?

Comment: 2. Maybe you can try 'collapse_key' instead?

Comment: what did u mean old GCM @larryp ? I tried "collapse_key" too but it didn't work

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I ended up using this with no choice .

Answer (score 0):

I think here you'll find the answer https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md

You can send almost anything in that array, but some special keys will trigger special message structure or behaviour.